# Phoenix Framework Channels - (ErlangError) erlang error: [reason: :function_clause, mfa: {Phoenix.Endpoint.CowboyHandler

Tags: websocket, elixir, phoenix-framework

I was trying out Phoenix and wanted to make a simple websocket chat app but I'm stuck on this error:

What I'm doing is creating a channel that I can successfully join, but when trying to send events I get an error: `(ErlangError) erlang error: [reason: :function_clause, mfa: {Phoenix.Endpoint.CowboyHandler ...`

I have a gist with my code and the full error here: https://gist.github.com/jurre/28796f8c4ad9e4122f18

I'm using Elixir 1.0.2 and Phoenix framework v0.7.2. I'm very new to both elixir and phoenix and this may be something very obvious.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I asked the same question on irc and Jose Valim helped me out.

I was matching on:

```
def event(socket, "new:message", %{ message: message })
```

But I should have been matching on:

```
def event(socket, "new:message", %{ "content" => content })
```

Comment: It seems like I have to wait for another day before I can accept it :)